# Refactoring where unique functions have different arguments

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class (acting as a wrapper over a library) with member functions that all follow this pattern:

```
MyObject& MyObject::ObjectFunction(int arg1, std::string arg2)
{
    LibraryObject destination_object;
    libraryFunction(destination_object, arg1, arg2);
    setProp(destination_object);
    ~destination_object;
    return *this;
}
```

I would like to refactor this so that the repeated steps (create destination object, set property, destroy destination object, return address) can be moved into a function of their own, ideally something like this:

```
MyObject& MyObject::genericFunction (uniqueLibraryFunction(Args)) 
{
    LibraryObject destination_object;
    uniqueLibraryFunction(Args);
    setProp(destination_object);
    ~destination_object;
    return *this;        
}

void libraryFunction1(int arg1, std::string arg2) 
{
    genericFunction(libraryFunction1(arg1, arg2));
}

void libraryFunction2(double arg1, int arg2) 
{
    genericFunction(libraryFunction2(arg1, arg2));
}
```

However I am using a library which has methods that require a destination object to return values to. I have tried to use variadic arguments but I can't seem to get it working since the library functions take different argument lengths and types. I have also tried to use pointer-to-function-members but couldn't get it working for the same reason (argument lengths and types differ between library functions).

My class code is the following:

```
class MyObject 
{
    private:
        LibraryObject prop;
    public:
        getProp();
        setProp(int prop);
}
```

Comment: `~destination_object;` - what is this?

Comment: why do you want to call the destructor (`~destination_object;`) ? The object will be destroyed twice

Comment: @user463035818: it won't be, it's definitely not an explicit call to destructor, it's more like an unary `operator~`

Comment: @AndriyTylychko yes it is not calling the destructor, though from what OP is writing it seems like this line is supposed to destroy the object

Comment: Your code is illogical... You declare `setProp` without argument but you call it with one, and you declare `libraryFunction1` and `libraryFunction2` as standalone function but  you access `genericFunction` which is a member-function of `MyObject`.... Please provide a working example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, then it should be doable with a lambda:

```
template <class F>
MyObject& MyObject::genericFunction(F f) 
{
    LibraryObject destination_object;
    f(destination_object);
    setProp(destination_object);
    return *this;        
}

void MyObject::libraryFunction1(int arg1, std::string arg2) 
{
    genericFunction([=](LibraryObject &o) { libraryFunction1(o, arg1, arg2); });
}

void libraryFunction2(double arg1, int arg2) 
{
    genericFunction([=](LibraryObject &o) { libraryFunction2(o, arg1, arg2); });
}
```

Alternatively, `std::bind` will do the same job:

```
void MyObject::libraryFunction1(int arg1, std::string arg2) 
{
  genericFunction(std::bind(libraryFunction1, std::placeholders::_1, arg1, arg2));
}
```

The template shouldn't be an issue, since if it's private, it could easily be implemented just in the source file where all the calls to it reside. However, if that's not an option for you for whatever reason, you can use `std::function<void(LibraryObject&)>` instead of `F`.